# How to Optimize this Database Layout MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to optimize saving and loading for a game server I'm working on. The current table looks like this (the table was created over 3 years ago, prior to when I joined this team):

[image]

The show create table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventoryitems` (
  `inventoryitemid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `characterid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inventorytype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `petid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `giftFrom` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryitemid`),
  KEY `CHARID` (`characterid`),
  KEY `inventorytype` (`inventorytype`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `accountid` (`accountid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79599139 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, there are 5 indexes on this table, which slow down saving by a lot. To clarify more on the indexes:

- **InventoryItemID**: primary index that is used for InventoryEquipment in the instance that the item being saved is considered equipment.
- **characterid:** important index that links the item to owner's character ID
- **inventorytype**: this index is used to determine which inventory tab the item goes to. There are several tabs, such as **EQUIP, USE, ETC**. The reason this exists is to prevent items being loaded to the same slot when they shouldn't be. Here is a sample image.

  [image]

As you can see, there are five different tabs. Each tab has slots for items to go into. The inventorytype segregates the items into these areas.

- **type**: Determines what type of save this is. In the game this disparages between 3 different categories. *Merchant items*, *Storage items*, and *Inventory Items*. This type determines how the items are loaded into the game. Inventory items are loaded when the character logs in. Storage items are loaded when they access the items through storage. Merchant items are loaded when players access them through the Merchant storage.
- **accountid**: Storage items are linked through storage. They are the only items that are linked through accounts and not characters

**Pondering**: It seems apparent to me that this table can be truncated. The accountid isn't even used often since it's only used for storage, so having that indexed is necessary to keep load times small, but really hurts saving. Furthermore, merchant items aren't saved by the slot, so it doesn't make sense to have them here.

**Solution**: Split them up into 3 different tables.
**Problem**: How? Below is a picture of how I tried to split them, but there is still an issue.

[image]

I don't know if this layout is doable since the top layer (Account, Merchant, Inventory) inserts first, but requires a key from the second layer (Items). Is there a better way to get around this? Or am I just looking at it wrong?

Here is my code in Java (game runs on Java) that does the database call to save:

```
public synchronized void saveItems(List<Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType>> items, int id, Connection con) throws SQLException {
        lock.lock();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append(
                "DELETE `inventoryitems`, `inventoryequipment` FROM `inventoryitems` LEFT JOIN `inventoryequipment` USING(`inventoryitemid`) WHERE `type` = ? AND `");
        query.append(account ? "accountid" : "characterid").append("` = ?");
        try {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query.toString())) {
                ps.setInt(1, value);
                ps.setInt(2, id);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `inventoryitems` VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                 Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                 PreparedStatement pse = con.prepareStatement(
                 "INSERT INTO `inventoryequipment` VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                LinkedList<Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType>> saved_items = new LinkedList<>();

                if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType> pair : items) {
                        Item item = pair.getLeft();
                        if (item.disappearsAtLogout())
                            continue;
                        MapleInventoryType mit = pair.getRight();
                        ps.setInt(1, value);
                        ps.setString(2, account ? null : String.valueOf(id));
                        ps.setString(3, account ? String.valueOf(id) : null);
                        ps.setInt(4, item.getItemId());
                        ps.setInt(5, mit.getType());
                        ps.setInt(6, item.getPosition());
                        ps.setInt(7, item.getQuantity());
                        ps.setString(8, item.getOwner());
                        ps.setInt(9, item.getPetId());
                        ps.setInt(10, item.getFlag());
                        ps.setLong(11, item.getExpiration());
                        ps.setString(12, item.getGiftFrom());
                        saved_items.add(pair);
                        ps.addBatch();
                    }

                    ps.executeBatch();

                    try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                        for (Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType> item : saved_items) {
                            int key = -1;
                            if (rs.next()) {                            
                                key = rs.getInt(1);
                            } else {
                                key = item.getLeft().getInventoryItemId();
                            }
                            MapleInventoryType mit = item.right; 
                            if (mit.equals(MapleInventoryType.EQUIP) || mit.equals(MapleInventoryType.EQUIPPED)) {
                                pse.setInt(1, key);
                                Equip equip = (Equip) item.left;
                                pse.setInt(2, equip.getUpgradeSlots());
                                pse.setInt(3, equip.getLevel());
                                pse.setInt(4, equip.getStr());
                                pse.setInt(5, equip.getDex());
                                pse.setInt(6, equip.getInt());
                                pse.setInt(7, equip.getLuk());
                                pse.setInt(8, equip.getHp());
                                pse.setInt(9, equip.getMp());
                                pse.setInt(10, equip.getWatk());
                                pse.setInt(11, equip.getMatk());
                                pse.setInt(12, equip.getWdef());
                                pse.setInt(13, equip.getMdef());
                                pse.setInt(14, equip.getAcc());
                                pse.setInt(15, equip.getAvoid());
                                pse.setInt(16, equip.getHands());
                                pse.setInt(17, equip.getSpeed());
                                pse.setInt(18, equip.getJump());
                                pse.setInt(19, equip.getVicious());
                                pse.setInt(20, equip.getItemLevel());
                                pse.setInt(21, equip.getItemExp());
                                pse.setInt(22, equip.getRingId());
                                pse.setBoolean(23, equip.hasSkill());
                                pse.addBatch(); 
                            }
                        }
                        pse.executeBatch();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Time to save " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogHelper.GENERAL_EXCEPTION.get().info("ItemFactory saveItems: " + e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

**Additionals**: I'm fairly new to database. Took one introduction to database and the rest of my experience has simply been from working on hobby projects and external ones. Also a college student!

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking. The amount of time spent saving a row shouldn't be an issue unless you are saving a lot (1000's) of rows at a time, or if you have many processes occurring in a short time (again, 1000's). Is something not working? If it isn't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: @SloanThrasher It's a pretty big issue at the moment since on the server when players save it can take up to 150-200 ms just to save the player items and merchant when they put one up. Now try to factor in players saving or putting up merchants at the same time and you have seconds of lag going on in the server directly related to the database saving.

Each item is being saved by batched then equipment.

Comment: ok, so the 2nd exception I mentioned is the case. Edit your question and add the SQL you are using to insert/update into the table. It may be that an additional index should be added. Usually, having more indexes is better than fewer, as long as they are useful. The index maintenance usually isn't the limiting factor speed wise.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Updated the post.

Comment: First suggestion is to name the columns in the INSERT statement. If the layout of the table changes (even if unlikely), the statement will break (and all like it). Also, not naming them can have a performance impact. You shouldn't be inserting the auto-incrementing column so be sure to leave it out of both the column list and values.

Comment: Also, you might test the timing of the DELETE and INSERT statements execution. I suspect the DELETE may be taking more time than the INSERT.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I've actually tested the DELETE v. the INSERT and the DELETE takes like 2-5 ms while INSERTING takes up to 80-150. I'll double check again and let you know just in case.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Whoah you're right. Deleting items takes 106 MS while saving is 6 MS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143729/discussion-between-jonathan-nguyen-and-sloan-thrasher).

Comment: @SloanThrasher In case you can't make the chat: I get 100 ms on delete and 7 ms on save. The 100 ms happens when multiple people are on and saving, etc. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot performance problems is very difficult indeed without knowing the *exact* queries that exhibit the performance trouble.  Please read this and [edit] your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Putting lots of single-column indexes into MySQL tables is generally harmful to performance unless those indexes are designed to accelerate particular queries. Often a couple of well-chosen compound indexes are much more effective than a lot of single-column indexes. Read http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @O.Jones Okay Ill give it a look. Does the new diagram for the proposed new tables work at all or no?